# Onclick capture data Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Everyone from the below mentioned code i want to capture   full date **2016-8-13** onclick of anchor tag

[image]

```
<th class="days_hours sat">
   <a class="date-days" href="#">
     <input type="hidden" value="satfulldate" id="satfulldate">2016-8-13
     <span id="saturday">13</span>-Sat
   </a>
</th>
```

Comment: Please share your javascript code with which you have tried to resolve your issue.

Comment: Your anchor tag contains input and span element, apparently these fields are also anchored.

Comment: yeah it's hidden i want to pass this date in my query..

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo   yes these fields are also anchored but how can i capture date

Comment: Your first problem is that tour HTML is invalid - you cannot have an `input` inside an `a` element. Also the `input` is a self closing tag. To set a value, use the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have an `input` as a child of an `a` element, and the `input` is a self-closing element. To set its value, use the `value` attribute.

From there you can hook a click event to the `a` and use the `prev()` method to retrieve the `input` and `val()` to get its value. Try this:

```js
$('.date-days').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).prev().val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th class="days_hours sat">
    <input type="hidden" value="2016-8-12" class="frifulldate">
    <a class="date-days" href="#">
      <span id="saturday">12</span>-Fri
    </a>
  </th>
  <th class="days_hours sat">
    <input type="hidden" value="2016-8-13" class="satfulldate">
    <a class="date-days" href="#">
      <span id="saturday">13</span>-Sat
    </a>
  </th>
</table>
```

Comment: but i am appending value on the basis of id how can i pass date inside the value attribute

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense. Could you explain what you mean. It may be better if you updated your question to show more of your code.

Comment: above i have attached screenshot when user clicks on any date(suppose 14-Sun) i want to pass clicked date in my query so I can populate data according to date

Comment: Right - that's what my code above is showing you how to do. I added a second date to hopefully make it a little more clear for you

Comment: initially i do not have date i am appending my date document.getElementById("sundayfulldate").innerHTML =sunday_date;

Comment: Use `value`, not `innerHTML`. Also ensure you do not have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute